# List of Subpath strings Compared to List of FileInfo

Tags: c#, compare

I have the below method that is comparing a list (Rows) of subpaths to a `List<FileInfo>`, and adding any missing entries to a list `_missingImageFolderEnteries`. I'm using LINQ and have noticed it seems surprisingly slow to process. Any ideas why or thoughts on how to improve performance? Perhaps LINQ isn't right here but I thought it should be more efficient than standard looping.

```
private List<FileInfo> _imageFilesInFolderPathList = new List<FileInfo>();
private readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> _missingImageFolderEnteries = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
private void CrossCheckImageWithFolder(EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> Rows)
{
    foreach (var dr in Rows)
    {
        var filepath = dr[ImagePathHeader].ToString();

        if (!_imageFilesInFolderPathList.Any(row =>
            row.FullName.EndsWith(FilePathHandler.FormatSubPath(filepath))))
            _missingImageFolderEnteries.Add(
                new Tuple<string, string>(
                    filepath.Substring(CommonInitFolder.Length).StartsWith("\\")
                        ? filepath.Substring(CommonInitFolder.Length)
                        : "\\" + filepath.Substring(CommonInitFolder.Length),
                    " does not exist in image folder"));
    }

    _missingImageFolderEnteries.Sort((x, y) => y.Item1.CompareTo(x.Item1));
}

public static string FormatSubPath(string path, bool needsSlash = true)
{
    var returnPath = path;
    if (returnPath.StartsWith("."))
        returnPath = returnPath.Substring(1);
    if (!returnPath.StartsWith("\\") && needsSlash)
        returnPath = "\\" + returnPath;
    else if (returnPath.StartsWith("\\") && !needsSlash)
        returnPath = returnPath.Substring(1);

    return returnPath;
}
```

Comment: _" I thought it should be more efficient than standard looping"_ LINQ just hides the loop. Actually it's easier to write inefficient code with LINQ than with classic loops. But you can also use LINQ to write efficient code if you know what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is a level of abstraction so it could never be faster than manual loop.

As for your problem I would try converting `_imageFilesInFolderPathList` to `HashSet<string>` containing names of files. Also you will need to compare whole string insted of using `EndsWith` to get performance boost.

Comment: The reason I use `EndsWith` is because I won't know how long the path string (dr) will be, i.e. they are not full paths.